# Jquery lazyload plugin and html table issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use before the lazyload plugin and that works fine. when i put images in div then it works fine but when i put images in table TD then lazyload do not work. i search google lot to get any clue but found none. so please anyone help me how to solve this problem.

### here is my render html code from aspx file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table[id*=dgImages] img").lazyload({
    //$("#dgImages img.lazy").lazyload({
        placeholder: "http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif",
        effect: "fadeIn"
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="form1">
<table id="dgImages" cellspacing="4">
<tr>
    <td>
   <img class="lazy" src='http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif'  data-original='snapdeals/5052603_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" />
</td><td>
   <img class="lazy" src='http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif'  data-original='snapdeals/50584602_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" />
</td><td>
   <img class="lazy" src='http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif'  data-original='snapdeals/55403401_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" />

</td><td>
   <img class="lazy" src='http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif'  data-original='snapdeals/55572106_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" />
</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
   <img class="lazy" src='http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif'  data-original='snapdeals/55572202_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" />
</td><td>
   <img class="lazy" src='http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif'  data-original='snapdeals/55595101_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" />
</td><td>

   <img class="lazy" src='http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif'  data-original='snapdeals/5571601_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" />
</td><td>
   <img class="lazy" src='http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif'  data-original='snapdeals/60210801_M_1_2x.jpg' width="300px" height="300px" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i doubt the problem is in my below code from where i initiate lazyload

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table[id*=dgImages] img").lazyload({
        placeholder: "http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif",
        effect: "fadeIn"
    });
});
```

i also tried it with like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dgImages img.lazy").lazyload({
        placeholder: "http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif",
        effect: "fadeIn"
    });
});
```

but still no luck. so please guide me that when i datalist or gridview has many images then how could i load minimum images using jquery lazyload plugin. only those images will be download which are in visible area and when user scroll down then next set will download. please help me with code snippted and tell me where i need to rectify.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your images are not sequential, you can control loading behaviour with the `failurelimit` option. Try adding the following to your code:  `failurelimit : 10` thus:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dgImages img.lazy").lazyload({
        placeholder: "http://jquerystyle.com/-/img/ajaxLoader.gif",
        effect: "fadeIn",
        failurelimit : 10
    });
});
```

Setting failurelimit to 10 causes plugin to stop searching for images to load after finding 10 images below the fold.

Comment: sure i will try...please tell me one more thing that is there any option to add callback function with lazy like when each image download complete then that function will fire. thanks

Comment: sorry it does not work. i am alway getting a error scrollTop() is not function. the scrollTop() function is there lazyload.js but the same js i use in another project there i did not get any error. basically the problem occur when image is wrapped in table td. when image is wrapped in only div then no problem occur. if u have any idea then please share with me.

Comment: Do you have any more JavaScripts in your output file/rendered html?

Comment: no i have no javascript. i just work with two js file one jquery-1.4.1.min.js and query.lazyload.min.js. anyway can u plzz try my code in ur pc and get back to me with status. please let me know if u can sort the problem. thanks